# getting the path of a file in .Net library

Tags: .net, path

My library project is trying to open an XmlDocument from a file that's also contained in the library. How do I get the path of a file in the library so I can open it?

The current directory is not useful and Server.MapPath returns me the path of the main web application (MVC), so how do I get the path of the file in the library?

------- Edit
The xml files are in a folder within the library project which wont exist when deployed. So it seems these files need to exist in a folder outside of the library (in a virtual directory in IIS for instance).

Steve

Comment: What do you mean by "in the library", exactly?  Is it compiled in as a resource, or under some subdir of the IIS application, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the path of the currently-executing program or assembly (I'm not sure that you are), use the `Location` property of the `Assembly` you're interested in:

```
string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

or

```
string path = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TypeInAssembly)).Location;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. think Im having a stupid day and imagining a folder structure for my library once deployed!!! Thanks anyway